# GET_POST doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, post

I have php webpage with js function:

```
function send_answer(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../path2file/file_mine.php',
        data: {dbf1:1, us:1, re:1},
        success: reload (), 
    });
    return false; 
}
```

I have created php with code inside

```
$dbf1=$_POST['dbf1'];
$us=$_POST['us'];
$re=$_POST['re'];


"UPDATE `table` SET `app` = '$dbf1' WHERE `user_id` = '$us' AND reqn= '$re'"
```

**DB connection and file-mine.php generally are ok.** If I run php with values ($dbf1=1;..) instead of $_POST everything is ok and mysql is updated.

WHEN I activate function send_answer () it just reloading page, not UPDATE mySQL. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you are *calling* `reload()`, whereas you just want to *pass* reload as the callback.

```
success: reload, // NO () HERE!
```

But also...

[image: xkcd]
<sup>> [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/327/)</sup>

Please learn about SQL injection before it is too late. Switch to [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) now, you'll be glad you did!

Comment: Awsome, never seen this one before ;)

Comment: I call reload () because I want to reload page. I have such function reload(). And I need to reload page after UPDATE mySQL

Comment: But you do *not* want to call it *immediately*, which is what you are doing. You want to *pass it as a callback* so that it is called *later*, *after* the update is done.

Comment: Yes. You are right. It's ok now. But how can I reload page after mySQL has updated?

Comment: Cause I read success - is a function to be run when the request succeeds

Comment: Right, you ***pass*** it a function. ***You do NOT call it***. I don't know how much clearer to make this.

Comment: Yes, I have made as you told reload without () and everything is ok. Thank you. Excellent knowledge from your side.